# I am trying to Read a file in javascript, How do i fix this?

Tags: javascript, filesystems

This error is shown when using this code on my page...

Failed to execute 'readAsFile' on 'FileReader': parameter is not of type blob.

```
    var fr = new FileReader();
    var e = fr.readAsText("images/adworks/ad_config.txt");
    var data = fr.result;
```

Help?

Comment: do you need to fetch the file first? or are you on node.js? FileReader() i thought was client side.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader the first warning seems to be exactly this.

Comment: @altruios i use a <script> tag in HTML.

Comment: right, so you can't just pass a Path and have it resolve in the readAsText() method, you need to fetch a response in a blob format(or just  proccessed data from a server)? I think the fetch() api can handle that... readAsText() can only be used SECURELY, as in user input, it can't read an arbitray Path and resolve a blob as a file... the security nightmare that would be would be... well... gah. so you need to get that in an xmlHTTPS/AJAX/fetch() type. file processing is good in python or php, or node.js has Path File built in - and can both parse and serve to your client side code.

Comment: @altruios what is blob format?

Comment: blob is i think best described as arbitrary data, used a lot for images and files.